Unable to Retrieve the Correct Size of On-Screen Keyboard (TabTip.exe) Using Win32 APIs
I am currently working on a C# application where I am trying to interact with the On-Screen Keyboard (TabTip.exe) using Win32 API calls, specifically FindWindow, GetWindowRect, and SetWindowPos. However, I am encountering an issue where the size of the keyboard window is always returned as 0x0 (Width=0, Height=0) using GetWindowRect, even though I can see the keyboard on screen.
Steps I’ve Taken:
I start the On-Screen Keyboard (TabTip.exe) using Process.Start().
I use FindWindow to locate the window by its class name (IPTip_Main_Window).
I attempt to retrieve the window size using GetWindowRect.
Even after waiting for the window to initialize, the dimensions are still reported as Width=0 and Height=0.
I’ve tried increasing the delay with Thread.Sleep() and also tried using FindWindowEx to search for child windows. Despite this, the window size still reports 0x0.
Could you please guide me on the following:
Why am I getting 0x0 for the window size of TabTip.exe?
Is there a better method or recommended approach for retrieving the size of system-level windows like TabTip.exe?
Are there any specific system configurations (like tablet mode) that affect how the window size is reported?
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class KeyboardControl
{
    // P/Invoke declarations
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindow(string lpClassName, string lpWindowName);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr FindWindowEx(IntPtr hwndParent, IntPtr hwndChildAfter, string lpszClass, string lpszWindow);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern bool GetWindowRect(IntPtr hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetWindowPos(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hWndInsertAfter, int X, int Y, int cx, int cy, uint uFlags);

    // RECT structure to hold window coordinates
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct RECT
    {
        public int Left;
        public int Top;
        public int Right;
        public int Bottom;
    }

    // Constants for window positioning
    static readonly IntPtr HWND_TOP = new IntPtr(0); // To move window to the top
    static readonly IntPtr HWND_BOTTOM = new IntPtr(1); // To move window to the bottom

    public void OpenKeyboard()
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\TabTip.exe")
        {
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden // Hide the keyboard process window
        };

        // Start the keyboard process
        Process keyboardProcess = Process.Start(startInfo);

        // Wait for the keyboard process to initialize fully
        WaitForWindowInitialization();

        // Try to find the main window handle of the TabTip process
        IntPtr hwnd = FindWindow("IPTip_Main_Window", null); // Class name for TabTip

        // If not found, try looking for child windows of TabTip
        if (hwnd == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            hwnd = FindWindowEx(IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, "IPTip_Main_Window", null);
        }

        // If still not found, print the failure
        if (hwnd == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("On-Screen Keyboard window not found.");
            return;
        }

        // Optionally resize the window (even if GetWindowRect reports 0x0)
        ResizeKeyboardWindow(hwnd, 800, 200); // Resize to 800x200

        // Get the current size of the keyboard window (even if it reports 0x0, we force resizing)
        RECT rect;
        if (GetWindowRect(hwnd, out rect))
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Current Keyboard Window Size: Width={rect.Right - rect.Left}, Height={rect.Bottom - rect.Top}");
        }
    }

    public void WaitForWindowInitialization()
    {
        int retries = 10;  // Retry 10 times
        IntPtr hwnd = IntPtr.Zero;

        while (retries > 0 && hwnd == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            hwnd = FindWindow("IPTip_Main_Window", null); // Search for the TabTip window
            if (hwnd == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Waiting for keyboard window...");
                System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000); // Wait for 2 seconds before retrying
                retries--;
            }
        }

        if (hwnd == IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to find the keyboard window after several retries.");
        }
    }

    public void ResizeKeyboardWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int width, int height)
    {
        RECT rect;
        if (GetWindowRect(hwnd, out rect))
        {
            // Resize and move the window (keep the current position and only resize)
            SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOP, rect.Left, rect.Top, width, height, 0);
        }
        else
        {
            // If GetWindowRect fails, try resizing directly without checking the size
            SetWindowPos(hwnd, HWND_TOP, 100, 100, width, height, 0); // Set to a fixed position
        }
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create an instance of KeyboardControl and open the keyboard
        KeyboardControl control = new KeyboardControl();
        control.OpenKeyboard();
    }
}


Why am I getting 0x0 for the window size of TabTip.exe?
Is there a better method or recommended approach for retrieving the size of system-level windows like TabTip.exe?
Are there any specific system configurations (like tablet mode) that affect how the window size is reported?
